How to implement a similar Cloud Provider Service on GNS3 Vm?
I am trying to implement a server/cloud that is able to store all the data from different network devices. Like AWS does. I want to show the benefit of storing the data on a server which can be accessed from all the PCs connected to the server / cloud. My question is: Is it possible to create something like this in GNS3 VM? If so, how?
